# Remove all subtrees below depth k from the original tree?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am absolutely stuck on this problem and have no idea where to go from where I am.  It fails every test I give it but I am not sure how to fix it.  The instructions are:
remove all subtrees below depth k from the original tree

Releveant info: 
- DO NOT change the Node class.
- DO NOT change the first line of any function: name, parameters, types.
you may add new functions, but don't delete anything
- functions must be recursive
- no loops
- each function must have exactly one recursive helper function, which you add
- each function must be independent --- do not call any function other than the helper
- no fields (variables declared outside of a function)

If you think I left out any information/code, please let me know.

Relevant code:

```
private Node root;
private static class Node {
    public final int key;
    public Node left, right;
    public Node(int key) { this.key = key; }
}



public void removeBelowDepth(int k) {
    removeBelowDepthHelper(root, 0, k);
    }
private void removeBelowDepthHelper(Node node, int currentDepth, int k) {
    if (node == null) return;
    if (currentDepth == k) {
        node = null;
        return;
    }
    removeBelowDepthHelper(node.left, currentDepth + 1, k);
    removeBelowDepthHelper(node.right, currentDepth + 1, k);
    }
```

Comment: Hint #1: Setting `node` to `null` in your helper function doesn’t actually do anything.  It is just a parameter, which is forgotten when your function exits.  You’ll have to set something else to `null`.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to remove all nodes in your tree that fall strictly below a certain removal depth? In that case recurse down to that depth and set the left and right children to null. The point is to visit all nodes you will be removing from in your tree (left to right or right to left).

Answer (score 2):

I took AJ's advice and simply changed the null call and it works flawlessly!  Thank you guys so much!

```
public void removeBelowDepth(int k) {
        removeBelowDepthHelper(root, 0, k);
        }
        private void removeBelowDepthHelper(Node node, int currentDepth, int k) {
        if (node == null) return;
        if (currentDepth == k) {
            node.left = null;
            node.right = null;
            return;
        }
        removeBelowDepthHelper(node.left, currentDepth + 1, k);
        removeBelowDepthHelper(node.right, currentDepth + 1, k);
        }
```

Comment: Perfect.  Remember to mark this answer as solving the problem (click the grey check mark on the right to turn it green).

Comment: I can accpet it in two days, but I'll be sure to do it then!